# Is there any way to list all files in a Mac terminal that have a specific owner?

Tags: macos, mac, macports

In my case the ownership would belong to Macports, which I removed. However, I found there are still some files here and there that apparently belong to Macports and I would like to remove them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` tool for that:

```
find /path/to/search -user <username>
```

or if you want to list only files from current dir without subdirectories

```
find /path/to/search -maxdepth 1 -user <username>
```

Prepend `-ls` to have the output more like `ls`

```
find /path/to/search -user <username> -ls
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot that did the trick! (StackExchange wants me to wait 5 minutes for accepting your answer though...)

Comment: One more question though. Does this also show hidden files?

Comment: It will also show files starting with `.`, yes.